Flutter - Change background color on hover
I'm currently started learning flutter and I want to change color of container on hover, I tried my each time I got an error.
 MouseRegion(
            cursor: SystemMouseCursorsclick,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: (){},
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Text(
                  'Container',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    color: Colors.black,
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.black38,
                          blurRadius: 10,
                          spreadRadius: 1,
                          offset: Offset(1, 3))
                    ]),
              ),
            ),
          ),


import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: HoverContainer(),
    );
  }
}

class HoverContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  const HoverContainer({super.key});

  @override
  State<HoverContainer> createState() => _HoverContainerState();
}

class _HoverContainerState extends State<HoverContainer> {
  Color _containerColor = Colors.blue; //default container color

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: MouseRegion(
          onEnter: (_) {
            setState(() {
              _containerColor = Colors.red;
            });
          },
          onExit: (_) {
            setState(() {
              _containerColor = Colors.blue;
            });
          },
          child: Container(
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
             decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: _containerColor
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}



